# What is the purpose org.apache.jena.sparql.core.GraphView in jena

Tags: jena

as the title suggest, i am trying to understand the purpose of `org.apache.jena.sparql.core.GraphView` in the Jena Architecture. I'm currently studying the SPI.

the doc says:

> Implement a Graph as a view of the DatasetGraph. It maps graph operations to quad operations. GraphUnionRead provides a union graph that does not assume quads, but loops on graphs.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/core/GraphView.html

I wonder more in which context this is used, as in at a high level, what is the intrinsic purpose of the class ?

Regards,

Maat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a "view" in the database sense.

`DatasetGraph` is a collection of graphs, a default graph and zero or more named graphs. It has operations to give access to the default `getDefaultGraph` and any named graph `getGraph`. These graphs can then be used with the `Model` API.

Some (in fact, most) `DatasetGraph` store data as a set of triples and a set of quads. `GraphView` presents the `GraphAPI` leaving the storage in-place. Changes through a `GraphView` do update the underlying `DatasetGraph`, directing a triple add/delete to the right part of the DatasetGraph, and for named graph view, converting to a quad add/delete.
Transactions on a `GraphView` are transactions on the `DatasetGraph`.

Comment: I guess put differently. At the essence, why do we need to see a datasetGraph as a graph in the first place, may help me understand better.

Comment: Here is what i have notice so far. Starting from DatasetGraphFactory 2 classes of DatasetGraph use GraphView : `DatasetGraphTDB` and `DatasetGraphInMemory`. What they have in common is their back end if i may say, both are based on TripleTable and QuadTable. When they graph is requested the DataSet get warpped into the View e.g. `GraphNonTxnTDB` or `GraphInMemory` which are GraphView

Comment: However this is opposed to `DatasetGraphMap` or `DatasetGraphMapLink` which respectively use `DatasetGraphFactory.graphMakerMem` and `graphMakerNamedGraphMem` for their default graph for instance. Which if we follow the call, end up calling `Factory.createGraphMem( );` Where a GraphMem is actually a Graph backed an in memory tripleStore `GraphTripleStoreMem`

Comment: It seems like, when the DatasetGraph type is one backed by a "real storage structure"  (in Memory or Persistant) which ultimately contains the "graphs" of the dataset(albeit expressed in the storage language), to access these graph and work with them, the GraphView Wrap the Entire DataSet, with the appropriate URI, that let us know which underlying graph to tap on (e.g. union of all).

Comment: It seems that is a (graph) View or more precisely a set of Graph view on the Backend of a DatasetGraph, that is, something that allow to work with the backend of a dataset, when that backend is not a "jena graph" i.e. Graph expressed according to the underlying structure.

Comment: However, if the backend is expressed as in memory jena graph which is basically a graph mem, then there is no need for the GraphView.

Comment: If it is not a Jena storage, it would implement the DatasetGraph interface. It may find GraphView useful - it may not - depends on the nature of the implementation.

Comment: The older DatasetGraphMap and DatasetGraphMapLink do indeed implement using a collection of graphs. They aren't the scalable backends. DatasetGraphMapLink allows a collection of graphs from any source. Neither support MR+SW (multieple reader AND a single writer) transactions, only MRSW. By default , Fuseki uses DatasetGraphInMemory not DatasetGraphMap.

Comment: Understood !!! Thank u for the detailed explanations on this. Really helped